# Really customized themes

Tags: theming

I've been toying around with Drupal 7 for a couple of weeks now, and I think I understand how the theming system works, but I have a question.

I'm looking at Zen's default theme right now, and I understand that you're supposed to tweak the CSS files in the starterkit to begin building a more substantial sub-theme, but what if I wanted to change the layout of the page altogether?

Currently the Zen theme has the regions laid out something like this (please pardon the massively crude drawing, I just wanted to illustrate something):

[image]

And if I wanted it to be laid out like this instead:

[image]

Which of the theme files am I supposed to edit/hack? I'm assuming it's either page.tpl.php or html.tpl.php. Or is this something that's supposed to be done with CSS?

Answer (score 5):

Like Countzero said, regions is the Drupal way. If we have a look at the `seven.info` file of the Drupal theme Seven:

```
regions[content] = Content
regions[help] = Help
regions[page_top] = Page top
regions[page_bottom] = Page bottom
regions[sidebar_first] = First sidebar
regions_hidden[] = sidebar_first
```

You could simply add your banner here.

```
regions[content] = Content
regions[banner] = Banner
regions[help] = Help
regions[page_top] = Page top
regions[page_bottom] = Page bottom
regions[sidebar_first] = First sidebar
regions_hidden[] = sidebar_first
```

`page.tpl.php` would be the best place to print your banner, again we have a look at the Seven theme.

```
<div id="branding" class="clearfix">
  <?php print $breadcrumb; ?>
  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <?php if ($title): ?>
    <h1 class="page-title"><?php print $title; ?></h1>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
  <?php print render($primary_local_tasks); ?>
</div>

<!-- Print our custom banner region! -->
<!-- START {{{ -->
<?php if ($page['banner']): ?>
  <div id="my-awesome-banner"><?php echo $page['banner']; /* echo is faster then print */ ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- }}} END -->

<div id="page">
  <?php if ($secondary_local_tasks): ?>
    <div class="tabs-secondary clearfix"><ul class="tabs secondary"><?php print render($secondary_local_tasks); ?></ul></div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <div id="content" class="clearfix">
    <div class="element-invisible"><a id="main-content"></a></div>
    <?php if ($messages): ?>
      <div id="console" class="clearfix"><?php print $messages; ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($page['help']): ?>
      <div id="help">
        <?php print render($page['help']); ?>
      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($action_links): ?><ul class="action-links"><?php print render($action_links); ?></ul><?php endif; ?>
    <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <?php print $feed_icons; ?>
  </div>

</div>
```

Hope this helps. Of course this is absolutely basic stuff and should only help you getting started.

Comment: Actually for the banner area you'd just say print render($page['banner']). This would allow users to put whatever they want into the banner region. If the banner region is only supposed to contain an image, then just output the image tag without defining a new region.

Comment: Absolutely correct! Edited the code.

Answer (score 5):

Different layouts for different pages is one of the many things that the [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) module can do.  It works alongside your base theme.  The base theme sets up general things, gets your site looking consistent, and gives you the opportunity to customize it.  Panels gives you much greater flexibility for creating different layouts for different parts of your site, than the normal blocks in regions combo gives you.

Comment: @cornjuliox In addition, adding the 'panels_everywhere' module with Panels can totally bypass the theme system and may make styling your customized pages much easier.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I was looking for. I'm gonna try it out.

Comment: I'm not saying that Panels isn't a well written and powerful module (even if I don't really like it myself), but if you really want to understand the Drupal theme layer, I would try to do it *without* Panels first.

Answer (score 3):

Using Zen, or any other theme for this matter, the concept in Drupal is Region, which are defined in the theme.info file, in the form :

`regions[title] = title_region`

regions[body] = body_region
...

You then have to output $title_region and $body_region in the relevant theme files, i.e page.tpl.php for D6.

The overall layout must of course be handled in the CSS file, as in layout.css.